# How do you install qt on ubuntu22.04

Tags: qt, 22.04

In ubuntu20.04 `qt5-default` was the package name. So I tried the same and `qt6-default` in 22.04.

Then I tried `apt-cache search qt` which revealed (among many others): `qt6-base-dev` and `qt5-base-dev`.

I am unsure whether the new qt{version}-base-dev is the old `qt5-default`. If not: What is?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I needed this for Linux kernel 5.4 compilation.

Comment: Instead of Qt6 I went with Qt5 as it was having one header installation error as that header got deprecated in the Qt6

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to install packages:

```
sudo apt install -y qtcreator qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake cmake
```

And you need to manually change the Qt version:
[screenshot how to manually change Qt version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaHmu.png)

Then you need to manually change Qt version in the Kits tab:
[screenshot on the Kits tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Iwe.png)

Comment: i sure hope this works on the standard raspberry pi os.  i'm having problems gettin apt to install qtcreator on there.  Well, not qtcreator - that's on fine.  But the qt kit can't be found.  Hoping that's in the qtbase5-dev.  I'll give it a shot.  thanks!

Comment: That -does- work to install qtcreator (and especially the proper kit stuff) onto raspberry pi (regular 32 bit os).  That helped me a looot - thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on amd-64 Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Is there any documentation page for this?

Comment: This sort of OVER-answers the question.  What about for a "client" machine which only needs the Qt libraries to run programs?  qt-default used to take care of that.  What now?  qtchooser doesn't install any libraries.  qt5-base no longer exists either.

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu 22.10 qtcreator's dependencies are all from Qt6 (see `apt-cache depends qtcreator | grep qt6`). `qtbase5-dev` is still there though (and automatically installs `qt5-cmake`), so just `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev` is sufficient for basic Qt5.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Ubuntu 22.04, you can use `qt6-base`, `qt6-base-dev` or `qt6-tools-dev`

Comment: Unable to locate package qt6-base

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you install it with their [online installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer).

Once downloaded, `chmod +x qt-unified-linux-<arch>-<version>-online.run` then `./qt-unified-linux-<arch>-<version>-online.run`

Comment: I try to use the package manager whenever I am able, but you are right given my question.

Comment: @Natan I tried the same thing. Maybe it'll get there in the future since 22.04 is relatively new.

Comment: Unfortunately, the online installer does not run on arm64 architecture.

Comment: @Dragos You can also build from source if you are unable to use the installer.

Comment: this is a good answer and will get you the latest qt6.2+  BUT if you want to use the qt that came with your distro (especially if you use Kubuntu - which i guess you don't) then sudo apt install answer is the way to go if you want to distribute .deb files on kubuntu.  which i guess you don't :)

Comment: @StephenHazel Unless it's changed (doubtful), you can install Qt 5.x through this installer as well.

Comment: not 5.15.3 that is used by kubuntu 22.04.  you can sudo apt install it on kubuntu, but the online installer goes from 5.15.2 to 6.0.  I think cuz KDE started maintaining bug fixes on the last 5.x line as they couldn't move to 6 yet.

Answer (score 0):

For all who just want to install `vulkan-sdk` on Ubuntu 22.04 like I wanted, getting the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vulkancapsviewer : Depends: qt5-default but it is not installable
```

These instructions helped in my case: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.3.236.0/linux/getting_started_ubuntu.html

```
wget -qO- https://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/lunarg.asc
sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-jammy.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/lunarg-vulkan-jammy.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
```

Comment: Why giving information about the vulkan SDK since the topic is to install Qt ?